# Double-quotes in a Javascript generated string issue

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, double-quotes

I am loading some text from a file in a node js application using something similar to the following:

```
var retr = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + tmp).toString();
```

The files contains a string similar to: `a"a`

I am using that string to generate a constant value using double quotes:

```
var MY_CT ="a"a";
```

Of course, node complains this code is not valid.

How can I transform the double-quotes to init `MY_CT` properly? I can't modify the source file itself. The source file is not HTML, it is plain text.

Comment: `var MY_CT ='a"a';` To escape quotes, cover double quote with single quotes and vice versa

Comment: "I am using that string to generate a constant value using double quotes" - do explain, because that's really the only interesting part.

Comment: MY_CT is in a Javascript file which can be loaded from user side. It is generated once.

Comment: So fix how it is generated (and the only interesting part, the generation, is not shown). Story done. Anyway, `JSON.stringify(a_string)` will return a valid JavaScript string literal, including quotes (well, [almost](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset)).

Comment: Just a guess: Escaping? `"a\"a"`

Comment: @23tux Yes, but what is the code to escape the double quote in retr? That's my question.

Comment: `retr.split('"').join('\"')`

Comment: @23tux If the file contains `\"` that will result in `"\\""` which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understood is that you have a variable (let's call it `x`) which contains a random string, read from a file, which can contain single quotes or double quotes and you want to generate a file containing that string between quotes so it can be interpreted in JavaScript.

The solution would be:

```
JSON.stringify(x)
```

This will return in your case: `"a\"a"` which is valid. This will also work when your file contains single quotes.

Comment: There is a [very slight edge case](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), but this is definitely the approach I would initially use out of convenience and ubiquity.